# There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).Forbiden

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new in spring.
I was trying to add a new goal to my database. Before I add spring security it's worked, but now if I click to add a new goal, I have a problem :

There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden

My goat-add.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Goals</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<header th:insert="blocks/header :: header"></header>

<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <h1>Your goals</h1>
    <form action="/goal/add" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Write your goal name" class="form-control"><br>
        <textarea type="text" name="description" placeholder="Write your goal description" class="form-control"></textarea><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add goal</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div th:insert="blocks/footer :: footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

WebSecurityConfig class :

```
package com.evgzabozhan.GoatGoal.config;
import com.evgzabozhan.GoatGoal.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login","/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    }
}
```

My controller :

```
package com.evgzabozhan.GoatGoal.controller;

import com.evgzabozhan.GoatGoal.model.Goal;
import com.evgzabozhan.GoatGoal.model.User;
import com.evgzabozhan.GoatGoal.repository.GoalRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.*;

@Controller
public class GoalController {

    @Autowired
    private GoalRepository goalRepository;

    @GetMapping("/goal")
    public String goal(Model model){
        Iterable<Goal> goals = goalRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("goals",goals);
        return "goal/goal-main";
    }

    @GetMapping("/goal/add")
    public String getGoalAdd(Model model){
        return "goal/goal-add";
    }

    @PostMapping("/goal/add")
    public String postGoalAdd(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                              @RequestParam String name,
                              @RequestParam String description, Model model){

        Goal goal = new Goal(name,description,user);
        goalRepository.save(goal);
        model.addAttribute("message",user.getUsername());
        return "redirect:/goal";
    }

    @GetMapping("/goal/{id}")
    public String goalInfo(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {
        if (!goalRepository.existsById(id)) {
            return "redirect:/goal";
        }

        Optional<Goal> goal = goalRepository.findById(id);
        ArrayList<Goal> result = new ArrayList<>();
        goal.ifPresent(result::add);
        model.addAttribute("goal", result);
        return "goal/goal-info";
    }

    @GetMapping("/goal/{id}/edit")
    public String goalEdit(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model){
        if (!goalRepository.existsById(id)) {
            return "redirect:/goal";
        }

        Optional<Goal> goal = goalRepository.findById(id);
        ArrayList<Goal> result = new ArrayList<>();
        goal.ifPresent(result::add);
        model.addAttribute("goal", result);
        return "goal/goal-edit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/goal/{id}/edit")
    public String postGoalUpdate(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id,
                                 @RequestParam String name,
                                 @RequestParam String description,
                                 Model model){
        Goal goal = goalRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        goal.setName(name);
        goal.setDescription(description);
        goalRepository.save(goal);
        return "redirect:/goal";
    }

    @PostMapping("/goal/{id}/remove")
    public String postGoalRemove(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model){
        Goal goal = goalRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        goalRepository.delete(goal);
        return "redirect:/goal";
    }
}
```

I read this problem can be if don't use csrf, but I don't understand how I can fix it.

All code there: https://github.com/evgzabozhan/GoatGoal

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add .csrf.disable() in configure method and it's work.

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login","/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

it's working because crsf is enabled on default in Spring

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because none of the goal calls is a permitted operation

```
.antMatchers("/login","/registration").permitAll()
```

should be

```
 .antMatchers("/login","/registration","/goal").permitAll()
```

Comment: Thank you, but that does not work. Before I can add a new goal I need authorization. After authorization, I can add a new goal for the user under which I login